# Lua - Count the no. of references to a table

Tags: memory-management, reference, garbage-collection, lua

The Lua docs say

> When a program has no references to a table left, Lua memory
>   management will eventually delete the table and reuse its memory.

My question is :  Is it possible to count the no of references to a particular table during runtime?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all references to a Lua value using the debug library. See these messages:

- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-03/msg00479.html
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-04/msg00758.html

The luatraverse library found in the below link solves this nicely!
http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/luatraverse/summary

Comment: Yeah! `luatraverse` does it nicely!
http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/luatraverse/summary
Updated your answer!