# What do we actually mean by like objects,tables have a STATE and tables are objects in more than one sense programming in OOP and data structures?

Tags: oop, data-structures, lua, roblox

i have been learning a roblox lua language and many times i have came across something called table has a state like objects line and i really don't understand that as i don't how to visualize it,like what it actually means

i have been reading this roblox lua article and have came across this line again: Object-Oriented Programming(https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Object-Oriented-Programming)

this is some bit of that article and it contains that line:

> As Lua supports duck typing through the use of Metatables, the ability to create “objects” can be achieved. This is essentially objected-oriented programming. A Tables in Lua is an object in more than one sense. Like objects, tables have a state. Like objects, tables have an identity that is independent of their values; specifically, two objects (tables) with the same value are different objects, whereas an object can have different values at different times, but it is always the same object. Like objects, tables have a life cycle that is independent of who created them or where they were created.

can somebody help me with this i have been trying search this on google but nothing similar shows up,like what actually it is?also what do we mean by tables as objects?

Comment: A table is a container: it can have inner members (both data fields and functions) which can be changed without changing the container. IMO, it's the content of a table which is called "a state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to think about tables is that they are dictionaries or associative arrays. They can also act like regular arrays and lists too. But under the hood, they are storing values in a key-value pair system.

With that in mind, let's just break down that paragraph into each line talk about what it all means.

1)  **As Lua supports [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) through the use of Metatables, the ability to create “objects” can be achieved. This is essentially objected-oriented programming.**

This means that if an object walks like a duck and quacks like a duck it can reasonably be expected that it is a duck. Lua doesn't technically have OOP classes, but we can make lua tables walk and quack like OOP classes.

When you create an instance of a class in other programming languages, that instance has all the properties, functions, and fields of that class type. In lua, we can make tables pretend to do that by messing with [metamethods](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents).

```
local TestClass = {}
TestClass.__index = TestClass

function TestClass.new()
    local tc = {
        secret = "hello world"
    }
    setmetatable(tc, TestClass)

    return tc
end
function TestClass:printSomething()
    print(self.secret)
end


-- construct a new "object" of TestClass, and call one of its functions
local a = TestClass.new()
a:printSomething()
```

What's happening here is TestClass is overwriting its `__index` metamethod. This means that when a table tries to look up a key in its table, instead of looking up the index from its own table, it will use the table index of TestClass. The `new()` function creates a brand new table, then overwrites its metatable with TestClass's, ensuring that the new table behaves like the original TestClass object would.

So even though the `tc` object does not have an explicitly defined `new()` or `printSomething()` function, calling the functions on that object still works. This is how lua can fake being object oriented.

2) **A table in Lua is an object in more than one sense. Like objects, tables have a state.**

This simply means you can store things in tables like a container.

```
local a = {
    foo = 5
}

print(a.foo) -- 5
```

3) **Like objects, tables have an identity that is independent of their values; specifically, two objects (tables) with the same value are different objects**...

```
local a = {}
local b = {}

print(a == b) -- false
print(a == {}) -- also false
```

4) **whereas an object can have different values at different times, but it is always the same object.**

```
local a = {
    foo = 5
}
print(a) -- some table pointer id
a.foo = 10
print(a) -- still the same table pointer
```

5) **Like objects, tables have a life cycle that is independent of who created them or where they were created.**

[Lua tables are kept alive in memory based on how many objects have reference to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366693/lua-count-the-no-of-references-to-a-table). This means that their object lifecycle can exist outside of their original scope.

```
local function createTable()
    -- make a local table to this function
    local a = {}

    -- make a table to return to the program
    local b = {
        c = a
    }
    print("a = ", a) -- some table pointer
    print("b = ", b) -- some other table pointer
    return b
end

-- a is no longer in scope, and in other languages would be cleaned up
-- but since b holds a reference to it, it is not removed.
local d = createTable()
print("d =", d)  -- should print out b's table pointer
print("d.c = ", d.c) -- should print out a's table pointer
```

Hopefully this clears up some confusion.